# Assoc new key to every map in a list in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Given some function that computes a value given base on a map

```
(defn some-function [element] "some computation over element")
```

Is there a idomatic way of assoc'ing a new key for each element in a list of maps, where the value of the new key is computed by some-function?

Here is my naive approach:

```
(map 
  (fn [element] (assoc element :newkey (some-function element)))
  [{:a "map 1"} {:a "map 2"}])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks fine.

But you may consider using `#()` special macro instead of creating anonymous function yourself:

```
(map 
  #(assoc % :newkey (some-function %))
  [{:a "map 1"} {:a "map 2"}])
```